# CSRF Validation Failed in Drupal 7

Tags: angularjs, ajax, drupal-7

I've been searching and searching, including the many topics here, for a solution to my problem. I've had no luck thus far.
A bit of a backstory: I'm writing an AngularJS app with Drupal 7 as a backend. I'm able to login without problem, save Session Name and Session ID, and put them together for a Cookie header ([I had to use this "hack"](https://www.drupal.org/project/services/issues/1133084#comment-8433677)). Further, if I made a login call in the Postman app, then tried to update the node, it'd work. It makes me think  that there's a problem with session authentication, but I still can't figure it out.

That being said, I'm at a roadblock. Whenever I try to PUT to update a node, I get the following error:

```
401 (Unauthorized : CSRF validation failed)
```

Now, my ajax call looks like this:

```
  $http({
  method: 'PUT',
  url: CONSTANTS.SITE_URL+"/update/node/"+target_nid,
  headers:{
    'Content-Type': CONSTANTS.CONTENT_TYPE,
    'Authentication': CONSTANTS.SESS_NAME +"="+CONSTANTS.SESS_ID,
    'X-CSRF-Token' : CONSTANTS.TOKEN
  },
  data: {
    (JSON stuff)
  }
})
```

The CONTENT_TYPE is "application/json", the "Authentication" is the band-aid for the Cookie header problem, and the "X-CSRF-Token" is what is (presumably) giving me the problem. SESS_NAME, SESS_ID, and TOKEN are all gathered from the response at Login. I can pull lists made by users on the website, I can pull the list of all of the nodes of a certain type on the website as well. I only run into a problem when I attempt to PUT to update the node.

If I missed any information, let me know and I'll add it!

EDIT: I'm using AngularJS version 1.5.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying everything else, I followed one of the comments in the thread I linked at the beginning of my original post. They had to comment out a line in Services.module :

```
if ($non_safe_method_called && !drupal_valid_token($csrf_token, 'services')) {
  //return t('CSRF validation failed');
}
```

It's around line 590, plus or minus a few depending on how much you've messed with the file. I don't like doing it this way, but I can't for the life of me figure out why the token's not working right. It's a temporary fix, for sure, but if someone runs across this with the same problem in the future it'll hopefully help you out!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the line you could also add a true to drupal_valid_token

```
if ($non_safe_method_called && !drupal_valid_token($csrf_token, 'services',true)) {
  return t('CSRF validation failed');
}
```